# Node.js 0.12.7 writeFileSync and child process on Windows

Tags: node.js

My nodejs code writes http request to a JSON file and then calls a child process to run according to the parameters in that written JSON file.

```
app.post("/run_with_parameters", function(req, res){
     fs.writeFileSync("parameters.json", JSON.stringify(req.body));
     child_process.stdin.write("parameters.json"); //child process will read json and act accordingly
});
```

On the Windows machine, the "child process" sometimes get old parameters rather than the new one, which I suspect is because `fs.writeFileSync` doesn't finish writing to disk before returning to run the next statement. (according to [this post](http://www.daveeddy.com/2013/03/26/synchronous-file-io-in-nodejs/)).

Is this a Node.js bug/feature? Or it only exists on Windows machine?

Will it be better if I code this way?

```
app.post("/run_with_parameters", function(req, res){
     fs.writeFile("parameters.json", JSON.stringify(req.body), function(){
       child_process.stdin.write("parameters.json"); //child process will read json and act accordingly

     });
});
```

Does this guarantee the "child process" always gets the updated "parameters.json"?

Comment: Since you're using writeFileSync it's very odd that you're seeing this issue. Are you sure it's not related to some race condition with multiple requests?

Comment: i second the race condition hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

The article you linked to (while talking about ZFS specifically), indicates that neither of those file operations guarantee data has been written when the callback has finished. However the [`finish`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event of a stream says:

> When the end() method has been called, and all data has been flushed
>   to the underlying system, this event is emitted.

So you could use [`createWriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options), write to it and pipe to your child process on the `finish` event. If I'm interpreting the documentation correctly, your file will be there and have the content in it.